# How to call dll coded in C language with pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, import

I want to use a dll writen in C code, however, the interface of C function has a parameter of the pointer of an array . Then, how to pass the array to this C function in C#?

@param requestBuf The request buffer

@param requestBufferSize The request buffer size

Function want to call:

```
int WriteAnswer(unsigned char* requestBuf, unsigned int requestBufferSize)
```

I have imported this dll, the only problem is that: I don't know how to deal with the first parameter,because it needs a pointer of a buffer.

Comment: [Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To use a C function in C# you must create an extern method.

to create it, you can use [this application](http://pinvoker.com/). It gets the header file and gives you the extern method you need.

The information below are given from the forums of the application:

> P/Invoker .NET generates a .NET interface assembly (dll) when given a
>   number of C++ static dlls and a C++ header file (.h).
>
> It extracts the functions and variables exported by the C++ static
>   dll, finds their definitions in the C++ header file and from these
>   generates the .NET interface assembly (dll).
>
> The generated .NET interface assembly gives .NET applications access
>   to the functions and variables in the C++ static dlls.

Comment: was this answer usefull?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a wrapper in C# for your C++ DLL and function:

```
[DllImport("mydll", 
   CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl ,
   CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int WriteAnswer(IntPtr buffer, UInt32 bufferSize);
```

To call the function from C# you should allocate an **"unmanaged buffer"**, send to C++ and then cast it back to a string in C#:

```
IntPtr unmanagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
// Your Unmanaged Call
WriteAnswer(unmanagedBbuffer, 100);
string yourString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedBuffer);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedBuffer);
```

It's important to know which kind of string C++ is returning `PtrToStringUni` means **UTF16** (2 bytes per char). You may need a different function depending on the type of your string.